# Material UI Autocomplete list items have padding I can't get rid off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I have this Autocomplete component in a React app as:

```
 <Autocomplete
    placeholder="Enter Suburb"
    id="custom-input-demo"
    options={Suburbs.map((suburb) => suburb.suburb)}
    onChange={(event,value) => addSuburb(value)} 
    onFocus={()=>scrollToSuburb()}
    defaultValue={customer.suburb ? customer.suburb : ''}
    renderInput={(params) => (
    <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
      <input style={{ width: 300 }} placeholder="Type.."  type="text" {...params.inputProps} />
    </div>
        )}
        />
```

It appears with huge padding on the items as:

[Render screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhAzT.png)

I tried every possible way to alternate this style but wasn't able to.

What is the best way to style the Material UI react Autocomplete list?

Comment: There are various ways of adding styles to a material ui component. Using a theme (https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) for global styling. Or styles (https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) for custom component styles. You can even use styled components if you want.
But in this case, I think it's better to investigate _why_ the padding is applied and fixing it there, instead of adding extra styles here to patch up a problem.
Unfortunately it's not possible to find what's causing the issue without some more context. 
Adding a codesandox might be usefull.